# Javascript compare function behaving differently between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm sure I'm just missing some simple logic here and it is driving me nuts.

I'm working in Chrome v95.0.4638.69 and Firefox v93.0

I have an array of objects where the data looks like this:
[ {id:1, name:"Jake", active:true}, {id:2, name:"Sam", active:false} ]

and my compare function looks like this:

```
let compare = (a, b) => {
    const Aname = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const Bname = b.name.toUpperCase();
    if (a.active && b.active) {
        return Aname > Bname ? 1 : Aname < Bname ? -1 : 0;
    }
    else {
        return a.active ? 1 : -1;
    }
};
```

What I'm trying to do is all objects with active:true should be first with name sorted alphabetically followed by objects with active:false sorted alphabetically. In Chrome it does exactly that. In Firefox objects with active = false are at the top of the list. What dumb mistake am I making?

Comment: When the elements are not both active, you then only check `a`. You cannot rely on the order of the elements passed to your comparison function to be consistent; that is, a particular element may be passed sometimes as the first parameter (`a`), and sometimes as the second (`b`).

Comment: Your function should check the `active` flags first. If one is active and the other isn't, then return `-1` or `1` as appropriate to get the active ones first. Only if they're both active should you then go on to compare the names.

Comment: @Pointy That's effectively what she's doing.

Comment: @Barmar no it isn't, she doesn't check both elements if one isn't active. In any case the question wouldn't be here if it was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should sort by name when both objects have active set to the same value.
2. When sorting by the `active` property, `-1` should be returned if the first object has the property set to `true` to order it before the object with the property set to `false`.
3. You don't return `0` even if the two objects should be considered equal in the `else` branch.

```
let compare = (a, b) => {
    const Aname = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const Bname = b.name.toUpperCase();
    if (a.active === b.active) {
        return Aname > Bname ? 1 : Aname < Bname ? -1 : 0;
    }
    else {
        return a.active ? -1 : b.active ? 1: 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: That worked and I get why. Now I'm not even sure my code worked in Chrome. Thank you

Comment: @KathrynAdams Happy to help.